# Make socat write to (TCP or UNIX) socket line by line for log gathering

Tags: bash, sockets, logging, socat

I'm trying to merge several log files from multiple hosts. I'm doing a `socat -u EXEC:'follow_log_cmd' UNIX-SENDTO:/tmp/socket` for each log I want to follow.

On the log gathering machine I'm doing `socat -u UNIX-RECV:/tmp/socket -`

My problem is that log entries are getting overlapped sometimes because socat's not writing one line at a time, but instead a buffer at a time.

Is there any way to make it write one line at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a pseudo terminal to make socat's writing line buffered:

```
- socat -u EXEC:'follow_log_cmd' UNIX-SENDTO:/tmp/socket
+ socat -u EXEC:'follow_log_cmd',pty,ctty UNIX-SENDTO:/tmp/socket
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000674/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe